# HTML email bgcolor property not working correctly

Tags: php, html, html-table, html-email

I have been trying to send out html emails through a PHP mail script recently.  However every time I send the email it changes 
from

```
<html>
<body>
<table bgcolor="red">
<tr><td>How does this look?</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

to

```
<html>
<body>
<table bgcolor=\"red\">
<tr><td>How does this look?</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I prevent this because every time it causes the colors to change between a nasty black and lime green.

Comment: What changes where exactly? This needs more info, maybe show some code

Comment: How are you sending the email? Are you perhaps passing it through an `addslashes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape the quotes, use single quotes, or just remove them (not ideal I know) as your code seems to see those quotes and escape them for you otherwise.

For more information on your issue see addslashes:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: Note that PHP will not automatically escape quotes unless something is explicitly telling it to do so (like magic quotes or `addslashes()`)

Answer (score 1):

I think your webmail add \ for parse "
Test with gmail and thunderbird.

Use simple quote '

```
<html>
<body>
<table bgcolor='red'>
<tr><td>How does this look?</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to both of your guys comments!
The problem was magic quotes was enabled which I finally got disabled and it works perfectly!
Just had to post a new php5.ini file.